# What does the following logical expression $\phi_{M,S,k}$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory

I recently started my logic course. In my logic textbook I have the following logical expression and the exercise is to determine what it means:

> Let $M$ be a finite set, $S \subseteq2^M$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\phi_{M,S,k} := \bigwedge_{M'\subseteq M, |M'|=k} \left(\bigwedge_{i \in M'} X_i \land \bigwedge_{j \in M \backslash M'} \lnot X_j \land \bigwedge_{X \in S} \bigvee_{l \in X}X_l \right)$$

Comment: I think you must have copied it wrong.  The second $X_i$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RobPratt You are correct. I fixed it now.

Comment: It also seems like some of the $\bigwedge$ should instead be $\bigvee$.

Comment: @RobPratt No everything else is correct. I just rechecked it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the outer $\bigwedge$ were instead $\bigvee$, the expression would be asserting the existence of a $k$-subset that covers $S$.  If you interpret $X_i$ as a binary variable that indicates whether element $i\in M$ is selected, this proposition would be that the set covering problem of minimizing $\sum_{i\in M} X_i$ subject to $\sum_{i\in A} X_i \ge 1$ for all $A \in S$ has upper bound $k$.